# apt-get update install/update command isn't working

Tags: linux

```
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:18 http://cm.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 Packages [357 kB]
Reading package lists...
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file
```

Comment: Please i keep having this error when i want to update my ubuntu. i need help plse

Comment: My guess is you upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10, but [the PPA `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` doesn't support Ubuntu 18.10](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to switch from `cosmic` to `bionic` for this particular repository.  Here is a command that will do this for you:

```
sudo sed -i '/ppa\.launchpad\.net\/deadsnakes\/ppa/s/cosmic/bionic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Note that dependencies could be incompatible across major Ubuntu versions, but it shouldn't hurt to try using the `bionic` respository because it's either the repository doesn't work at all (like now) or the packages are incompatible (after the command).

After the command above, your `apt update` should succeed:

```
root@demo:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

---

## Explanation

The [PPA you are using](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) says that it doesn't support Ubuntu 18.10.  Description at the time of writing:

> ## Supported Ubuntu and Python Versions
>
> - Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) Python 2.3 - Python 2.6, Python 3.1 - Python3.4, Python 3.6 - Python3.8
> - Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) Python2.3 - Python 2.6, Python 3.1 - Python 3.5, Python3.7 - Python3.8
> - Note: Python2.7 (both), Python 3.5 (xenial), Python 3.6 (bionic) are not provided by deadsnakes as upstream ubuntu provides those packages.
>
> The packages may also work on other versions of Ubuntu or Debian, but
>   that is not tested or supported.

The PPA maintainer doesn't support your Ubuntu release, Ubuntu 18.10 (`cosmic`).